# Spring Cloud Stream Reactor Kafka Integration

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

Why do not we have direct integration for Reactive Kafka in Spring Cloud Stream?

Answer (score 0):

You can track [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/322) on Spring Kafka project on initial POC and I believe Spring Cloud Stream would make use of this once the final integration is done.